# Mock an attribute of a property of a class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I am having trouble mocking an *attribute* of a *property* of a *class*.

I have the following class:

```py
import boto3

class QueryFetcher:
    def __init__(self, query: str):
        self._query = query
        self._athena = boto3.client("athena")
    
    @property
    def athena(self):
        return self._athena
    
    def query_athena(self):
        # need to mock start_query_execution function
        execution = self._athena.start_query_execution(. . .)
        execution_id = execution["QueryExecutionId"]

        while True:
            # need to mock get_query_execution function
            stats = self._athena.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId=execution_id)
            . . .

        return status, execution_id
```

I have to mock the functions `start_query_execution` and `get_query_execution` which are part of the property `athena` in the class.

I am trying to unit test the function `query_athena`. This is a sample file for unit testing:

```py
import pytest
from query_fetcher import QueryFetcher
from unittest.mock import patch, PropertyMock


@pytest.fixture
def fetcher_user():
    return QueryFetcher(query="")


@mock.patch(
    "query_fetcher.QueryFetcher.athena",
    new_callable=mock.PropertyMock,
)
def test_query_athena(mock_athena, fetcher_user):
    mock_athena.return_value.get_query_execution.return_value = {
        "QueryExecution": {"Status": {"State": "SUCCEEDED"}}
    }
    mock_athena.return_value.start_query_execution.return_value = {
        "QueryExecutionId": "69320478-2452-465e-bc0d-89cdc8bd4428"
    }
    fetcher_user.query_athena()
```

However, this does not work and I assumed it's because I have to create a new instance of the class. So then I tried the following:

```py
@mock.patch(
    "query_fetcher.QueryFetcher.athena",
    new_callable=mock.PropertyMock,
)
def test_query_athena(mock_athena):
    mock_athena.return_value.get_query_execution.return_value = {
        "QueryExecution": {"Status": {"State": "SUCCEEDED"}}
    }
    mock_athena.return_value.start_query_execution.return_value = {
        "QueryExecutionId": "69320478-2452-465e-bc0d-89cdc8bd4428"
    }
    # create a new class instance
    fetcher_user = QueryFetcher(query="")
    fetcher_user.query_athena()
```

But this doesn't work either. What am I missing here?

Ideally, I'd like to mock the property `athena` on my fixture `fetcher_user` instead of creating a new instance entirely. I also do not want to modify my fixture to mock the functionality inside the fixture. Is that even possible?

I'd appreciate any help on this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```py
import mock

def test_query_athena(fetcher_user):
    fetcher_user._athena = mock.MagicMock()
    fetcher_user._athena.get_query_execution.return_value = {"QueryExecution": {"Status": {"State": "SUCCEEDED"}}}
    fetcher_user._athena.start_query_execution.return_value = {"QueryExecutionId": "69320478-2452-465e-bc0d-89cdc8bd4428"}
    fetcher_user.query_athena()
```

This also makes use of the fixture as I wanted and keeps things simple :)